# problems reading the head of a file in r for ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

I've used Rstudio on windows and for some reasons i had to change to Rstudio on Ubuntu. 
I've been trying to read a file from my directory, however when i use the `header = TRUE` i have the following error message
`Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, numerals = numerals`

My actual path is:
 `tal <- read.csv("Documents/Docs/Test/DaMx/Tla/Tula_General.csv", sep=";", dec=",", na.string = "nd", header = TRUE,  row.names =1 )`

I want to read my file with the first row as header, I have checked and there are not spelling problems. I can not see what is going wrong. Any help will be deeply apreciated.

I am using R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"

Comment: You should probably be using `read.csv2`, since your separator is a semi-colon and decimal mark is comma. Those are the proper defaults for that function. Posting the first few lines of the file as an edit to your question would be helpful if further advice is needed

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I'm posting the solution i found in case someone will need it.

My original data contained special characters, this doesn't seem to be a problem on Windows but is not the case for Ubuntu. So I change those special characters.